# If there is an injection from $A$ to $B$, is there an injection from $A\times C$ to $B\times C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

---

UPDATE:

Want to show $\exists$ an injection $g:(A \times C) \rightarrow (B \times C)$.

We assume $\#A \leq \#B \iff \exists$ an injection $h:A \rightarrow B$

We can let $g(a,c) = (h(a),c)$, where $h(a) \in B$

$(A \times C) = \{(a,c)$ $|$ $a \in A, c \in C\}$

$(B \times C) = \{(b,c)$ $|$ $b \in B, c \in C\}$

Assume that
$g(a_1,c) = g(a_2,c)$.

$g(a_1,c) = g(h(a_1),c)$

$g(a_2,c) = g(h(a_2),c)$

$\implies g(h(a_1),c) = g(h(a_2),c)$.

since $h(a_1) = h(a_2) \implies a_1 = a_2$,

$(a_1,c) = (a_2,c)$.

So such an injection $g$ exists.

---

Comment: Don't worry about whether the sets are finite, unless you run into difficulties with infinite sets. If you're given a 1-1 map $f:A \to B$, how do you come up with a 1-1 map $g:A\times C \to B\times C$? (Hint: $g(a,c) = (*,c)$.)

Comment: When comparing cardinalities, you will need the use functions at some point, at least in the beginning, because the definition of cardinality uses functions (or ordinals, but I guess that's not the definition you have).

Comment: Hmm well if the "y" values of both Cartesian products will be the values in the set $C$, then can my map just be the horizontal line $g(x) = c$?

Comment: Sorry, I think I mean $g(x,y) = y$ $\forall y \in Y$

Comment: What's $Y{}{}$?

Comment: I just mean to say that it would be whatever the second variable is. I am going to amend my post to reflect what I have currently

Comment: I made another update and hopefully I am getting closer to the correct conclusion. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several major problems with what you’ve done so far. First and most crucially, your function $g$ is a function from $A\times C$ to $C$, when what you need is an injection from $A\times C$ to $B\times C$.

Secondly, it’s not an injection if $A$ has more than one element. Suppose that $A$ has at least two elements, say $a_0$ and $a_1$; then the function $g:A\times C\to B\times C$ defined by $g(\langle a,c\rangle)$ is not an injection, since for any $c\in C$ we have $g(\langle a_0,c\rangle)=c=g(\langle a_1,c\rangle)$ even though $\langle a_0,c\rangle\ne\langle a_1,c\rangle$.

Finally, note that your definition of $g$ doesn’t use the hypothesis that $\#A\le\#B$; that’s a good indication that something is wrong.

HINT: Let $h:A\to B$ be an injection, and define $g:A\times C\to B\times C$ by $g(\langle a,c\rangle)=\langle h(a),c\rangle$.